# SELECT showing two COUNTs

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, count

I had this table:

tblA

```
id | name | value
1    nameA    1
2    nameA    0
3    nameB    0
4    nameC    0
5    nameC    1
6    nameC    1
```

As you see, Value can be 1 or 0

I need to perform a query that shows this for every nameX: nameX, count_1's, total_rows,

```
name  | 1's | total
nameA    1      2
nameB    0      1
nameC    2      3
```

I know that i can use GROUP by and COUNT. 
But don't see how to put the "total_rows" in same query.

This will give me name and number of 1's.

```
SELECT name, value FROM tblA WHERE value = "1" GROUP BY name
```

How to add the last column i need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a table called `cristian`, here is the needed query:

```
select name,SUM(value) "1s" ,SUM(1) "total"
FROM cristian GROUP BY name;
```

Here is your sample data:

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> drop table cristian;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> create table cristian
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ->     name varchar(25),value int not null
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into cristian (name,value) values
    -> ('nameA',1),('nameA',0),('nameB',0),
    -> ('nameC',0),('nameC',1),('nameC',1);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from cristian;
+----+-------+-------+
| id | name  | value |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | nameA |     1 |
|  2 | nameA |     0 |
|  3 | nameB |     0 |
|  4 | nameC |     0 |
|  5 | nameC |     1 |
|  6 | nameC |     1 |
+----+-------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and here is the query's output

```
mysql> select name,SUM(value) "1s" ,SUM(1) "total"
    -> FROM cristian GROUP BY name;
+-------+------+-------+
| name  | 1s   | total |
+-------+------+-------+
| nameA |    1 |     2 |
| nameB |    0 |     1 |
| nameC |    2 |     3 |
+-------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.14 sec)

mysql>
```

These would also work

```
select name,SUM(value) "1s" ,COUNT(1) "total"
FROM cristian GROUP BY name;

select name,SUM(IF(value=1,1,0)) "1s" ,COUNT(1) "total"
FROM cristian GROUP BY name;
```

## Give it a Try !!!